# Configure .xml properties file - log4j

Tags: java, xml, log4j

I have a properly working .xml propreties file for log4j, which sends logs to console output. But I want to exclude some excess information (which displayed when programm starts) from that output, such as:

```
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Level value for root is  [DEBUG].
log4j: root level set to DEBUG
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
// etc...
```

Is there any way to do it ?

My xml file  [is here](https://gist.github.com/damncoffie/3a6e8d15e25c8f9c19c432b75e8ea62b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line #3 of your configuration file set: debug="false".